# .htaccess mod rewrite for 10 letter alpha numeric "word"

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect people who add an Amazon ASIN (10 letters/numbers) to the end of my domain...

mydomain.com

I want them to format their url's like so:
mydomain.com/B008XCFLTM

Someone gave me:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}/(.*) /check.php?asin=$1 [L,R=301]
```

this works, only if they put the trailing slash like so:

mydomain.com/B008XCFLTM/

The following (removing the slash):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}(.*) /check.php?asin=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Kind of works.... I thought it worked but then any file above 10 characters would be caught by the Rewrite rule and sent to check.php.

Is there any way to limit it to just 10 characters?  So if anything after mydomain.com/ is 9 letters or less or 11 letters or less, it will work normally... if it's 10 characters only, have it redirect to check.php?

Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you trying to capture the ASIN number? The grouping (parentheses) needs to be around the ASIN, not whatever that comes after it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]{10})/?$ /check.php?asin=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: For some reason, when I use asin=$2, it doesn't work, but when I use your code above and I use asin=$1, it works like a charm! Thank you so much!

Comment: @R.J. Sorry, the `$2` is a typo, it should be `$1`

Comment: No prob... thanks so much for the super quick and helpful response!!